# Roughness map not effecting surface at all

Tags: roughness

The roughness map is not making a difference at all on the material. I made sure it has enough contrast.

heres the file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcvsk8g3vlvn092/Steam%20Shovel3.zip?dl=0

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: and don't forget to do file->external data-> pack resources before

Comment: here you go https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcvsk8g3vlvn092/Steam%20Shovel3.zip?dl=0

Comment: Try to add a multiply math function between the shader and the texture and increase its value.

Comment: I shouldn't have to do that. I've made other objects with roughness maps that was able to show up just by plugging them into the material.

Comment: From the image, i think you need more specular than zero. Roughness controls the how sharp or diffuse a reflection is. Specular controls the intensity of the reflection.

Comment: @Emir is right :) 0 specular means 0% reflectivity no matter the roughness :)

Comment: I think that did it, thanks!